# Node JS PATCH request running no matter what

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, patch

Sorry if the title if confusing, I wasn't too sure how to word it. I have a PATCH request to update a value in my database, but even though it is "working" (200 status), it's not actually.
I have a `.route('/:movie_id/:user_id').all()` handler to trigger for all my methods, where it pulls a movie from the database by movie_id and user_id. This works. Then I move on to my PATCH request, but it seems like the PATCH request isn't actually running. I am getting the correct response from the .all() handler, but no update is happening. Even if I completely comment out the code for my PATCH, I am still getting a 200 status.

Here is my .all() handler with my PATCH request:

```
movieRouter
    .route('/:movie_id/:user_id')
    .all(requireAuth)
    .get((req, res, next) => {
        const db = req.app.get('db')
        MovieService.getById(db, req.params.movie_id, req.params.user_id)
        .then(movie => {
            if(!movie) { // this runs fine
                return res.status(404).json({ error: `Movie doesn't exist`})
            }
            // res.json({movie : movie}); --> old code
            // solution:
            res.movie = movie;
            next();
            return movie;
        })
        .catch(next)
    })
    .patch(requireAuth, (req, res, next) => {
        const db = req.app.get('db')
        const { watched } = req.body
        const updatedMovie = { watched }

        // this doesn't run
        const numVal = Object.values(updatedMovie).filter(Boolean).length
        if(numVal === 0) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: `Must not be blank`})
        }

        MovieService.updateMovie(db, req.params.movie_id, req.params.user_id, updatedMovie)
            .then(movie => {
                res.status(200).json(updatedMovie)
            })
            .catch(next)
    })
```

Here is my MovieService:

```
updateMovie(db, movie_id, newMovie) {
        return db('your_movie_list').where('id', movie_id).where('user_id', user_id).update(newMovie).returning('*')
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the problem of the 2nd .all(), .all() will catch all request, no matter it is GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE. So even when you comment out PATCH code, it will return 200.

Change the 2nd `.all` to `.get` like below

```js
app.use(express.json())

movieRouter
    .route('/:movie_id/:user_id')
    .all(requireAuth)
    .get((req, res, next) => { // use .get instead of .all to avoid catching all requests
        const db = req.app.get('db')
        MovieService.getById(db, req.params.movie_id, req.params.user_id)
        .then(movie => {
            if(!movie) { // this runs fine
                return res.status(404).json({ error: `Movie doesn't exist`})
            }
            res.json({movie : movie});
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log("From getMovie", e); 
            res.status(400).json({ error: e.message }) 
        })
    })
    .patch((req, res, next) => { 
        try {
           const db = req.app.get('db')
           const { watched } = req.body
           const updatedMovie = { watched }

        
          // this doesn't run
          const numVal = Object.values(updatedMovie).filter(Boolean).length
          if(numVal === 0) {
              return res.status(400).json({ error: `Must not be blank`})
          }

          MovieService.updateMovie(db, req.params.movie_id, req.params.user_id, updatedMovie)
            .then(movie => {
                console.log(movie) // nothing logs 
                res.status(200).json(movie[0])
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log("From updateMovie", e); 
                res.status(400).json({ error: e.message }) 
            })
         }catch(e) {
             console.log("From try/catch", e); 
             res.status(400).json({ error: e.message }) 
         }
    })
```

A little working example for cross-checking

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.use(express.json())

const movieRouter = express.Router()
movieRouter
    .route('/:movie_id/:user_id')
    // .all(requireAuth)
    .get((req, res, next) => { 
        res.json({"movie:get" : 1});
    })
    .patch((req, res, next) => { 
        res.json({"movie:patch" : 1});
    })

app.use(movieRouter)

app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});
```

Comment: I know this is a really late reply, but I did what you suggested and now my patch request just keeps running. Postman says "Sending request" and I have to end up cancelling it.

Comment: so there must be something wrong in updateMovie method and it is catch and executed next but next is pointing to nothing, so it is going to black hole.

Comment: can you try changing the .catch to `.catch((e) => {console.log(e); res.status(400).json({ error: e.message }) })`. updated my answer as well.

Comment: added try/catch as well to wrap the whole code block, as there may be error in getting and processing the req.body as well.

Comment: I did try that but I'm not getting any logs since the request isn't going through. It seems like it's not getting past the first .get()

Comment: really !? wait a minute. let's me test the code

Comment: I tested without problem. I think it struck in jsonParser.     can you try to remove `jsonParser` and use `app.use(express.json())` instead. Code is updated as well. You can also try to copy the minimal example at the bottom to see if it is working.

Comment: Ok I think I got it! You were right, it was getting stuck at the jsonParser (although I don't understand why?), so I removed that. Then I got an error that was saying "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client," so I modified the .get() to save the response for the next middleware instead of sending it to the client right away. I modified my code in my original question

Comment: I didn't read your get as you said it is working. next()  and res.json() cannot be used together and I don't think you need `next()` in get and patch unless you have a global exception handling in the last. updated my answer as well